# jQuery scroll div with scrollTop

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to scroll a div up or down when hovering over the respective arrows. I also want to be able to jump down the div when the buttons are clicked (think clicking the windows scroll arrows rather than dragging the scroll bar).

The scrolling works but the jumping doesn't. scrollTop() keeps retuning 0.

Here's the code:

```
function startScrollContent()
{
   if ($('.haccordion-opened').prev('.header').find('div').attr('title') != 'dontscroll' && $('.haccordion-opened span.arrow').length == 0)
   {
      $('.haccordion-opened').append('<span class="arrow down" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 260px; font-size: 9pt;">&#9660;</span><span class="arrow up" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 280px; font-size: 9pt;">&#9650;</span>');

      $('.content span.arrow').hover(function()
      {
         direction = ($(this).hasClass('up')) ? '-=' : '+=';
         $('.content .padding').animate({scrollTop: direction + $('.content .padding').css('height')}, 5000);
      }, function()
      {
         $('.content .padding').stop();
      });

      $('.content span.arrow').click(function()
      {
         $('.content .padding').stop();
         direction = ($(this).hasClass('up')) ? '-' : '+';

         alert($('.content .padding').scrollTop());
         //$('.content .padding').scrollTop($('.content .padding').scrollTop + direction + 100);
      });
   }

   return;
}
```

How can I get the jump part working?

Comment: Did you try my code yet? How did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about [scrollIntoView()](http://rmassaioli.blogspot.com/2009/10/useful-javascript-scrollintoview.html) which you might find helpful to do exactly this type of jumping.

Comment: That would require me placing a new element every X pixels in the DIV so I can jump to it. Not as clean as I was hoping this to be...

Answer (score 0):

Without any arguements the scrollTop function returns the offset value. Use element.scrollTop(0) to scroll to the top. Here is a test that I ran which worked ok in FF and IE8 (but that [doesn't mean it will work in IE6](http://www.thunderguy.com/semicolon/2005/05/16/multiple-class-selectors-in-internet-explorer/)). I also changed some parts of your code because for some reason you had the hover and click events being bound to arrows that you wanted to find under the content tag (which isn't where you appended them to), you put them under the tag with the haccordion-opened class. Additionally the HTML you supplied used the haccordion class and not the haccordion-opened class as in your javascript. I changed the HTML to suit.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if ($('.haccordion-opened').prev('.header').find('div').attr('title') != 'dontscroll' && $('.haccordion-opened span.arrow').length == 0)
        {
            $('.haccordion-opened').append('<span class="arrow down" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 260px; font-size: 9pt;">&#9660;</span><span class="arrow up" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 280px; font-size: 9pt;">&#9650;</span>');

            $('.haccordion-opened span.arrow').hover(function()
            {
                direction = ($(this).hasClass('up')) ? '-=' : '+=';
                $('.content .padding').animate({scrollTop: direction + $('.content .padding').css('height')}, 5000);
            }, function()
            {
                $('.content .padding').stop();
            });

            $('.haccordion-opened span.arrow').click(function()
            {
                $('.content .padding').stop();
                direction = ($(this).hasClass('up')) ? '-=' : '+=';
                $('.content .padding').animate({scrollTop: direction + 100}, 0);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="haccordion-opened">
        <div class="header">
            <div title="blah"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="padding" style="height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
                <h4>Blah...</h4>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
                <p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. Find where the div is currently scrolled to (from the hover'd scroll functionality) - Which is, lets say, half way down the div. Then I want to increment that scoll by ~100 pixels. So the div will now be at half way + 100 pixels. Then the more you click, the further it jumps the div's scroll down. scrollTop(), however, keeps retuning the offset as 0. No matter how far down I scroll it.

Comment: Can you paste some abridged HTML so I can play and test?

Comment: What are you testing this in... because I am just reading up something about IE6 not handling multiple class elements well with jQuery.

Comment: Oh yeah and I changed the startScrollContent() name to just be under the document ready function, for my testing purposes.